# Drupal Views limiting content posted by group membership

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-views, organic-groups

I have various different content types and I want to filter by using views.

So say a block only displays content posted in groups that you are a member of. I've created my generic view which so far displays all content of that type, but I'm struggling with linking this to content only posted in groups your a member of.

I've looked at the Organic Groups filters but no luck there. I suspect I might need to use some sort of relationship but I'm stuck there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out you need to set a relationship between Organic Groups: Group node (post) and Organic Groups: group Member filter.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways of solving this.
The one which i preffer is using taxonomy to categorize the wanted content, and set the relashionships in the view depending on the category.
The second way is to use the relashionships depending of the content fields, from CCK.